# How to post json or form to WTForms Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask and WTForms and have this basic route. How would I allow both form creation from `request.form` or `request.get_json()` in case other external systems have to submit through API only and not through the UI?

The "solution" I came up with below seems to work, but I'm not sure if I should continue like this, or if there was a native solution within WTForms I am missing. Also I'm not sure if checking `if request.get_json() != None:` will always work for this case.

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, validators


class SomeForm(FlaskForm):
    some_name = StringField('some_name', [validators.required(), validators.length(max=2000)])


@some_blueprint.route("/some-route", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def some_input():
    form = SomeForm(request.form)
    if request.get_json() != None:
        form = SomeForm.from_json(request.get_json())
    else:
        form = SomeForm(request.form)
```